# Center single- AND multi-line li text vertically

Tags: css, list, center

I have an unordered list with a background-image set. All list-items have the same height, the background-image is positioned left center.

The text of each item should be **centered vertically** to the li. This works well with single-line text (by setting the line-height according to the height of the li), but not with **two lines of text**.

I could add "line-height:normal" to the two-line item, but I want a solution that works for all items.

How can I do this?

Example:

```
li { 
    list-style-type:none; 
    padding-left:40px; 
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px; 
    background:url('tick.png') no-repeat 0 50%; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code that we can see? It's much better for us if you can post what you've tried so far :)

Comment: in which browser you need to makes it work? Also IE6/7 ?

Comment: A CSS example:

li {
   list-style-type:none; 
   padding-left:40px;
   height:36px;
   line-height:36px;
   background:url('tick.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

If I have one line of text in the li, it works, but with two lines it does not.

Comment: It should work also in IE6 and 7.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

this is a most crossbrowser solution

```css
    li {
     width           : 200px;
        line-height     : 100px;
        height          : 100px;
     border          : 1px blue solid;        
    }
    li span {
     display    : -moz-inline-box;  /* FF2 or lower */
     display    : inline-block;     /* FF3, Opera, Safari */
        line-height         : normal;
        vertical-align      : middle;    
    }
    
    li span  { *display : inline;} /* haslayout for IE6/7 */
```

```html
<ul>
       <li><span>My text</span></li>
       <li><span>My longer text</span></li>
       <li><span>My text, but this time is really wide</span></li>
       <li><span>My text, some thoughts about how much it will expand in this item.</span></li>
    </ul>
```

I used star hack for brevity, you should avoid. Just use html5boilerplate solution, it uses conditional comments on body tag

Comment: Thanks for this, absolutely the best solution I've found, what a hero!

Comment: Better works without fixed height, `height: 100px;` in this example. More lines text resize area. Use `padding` or `margin` also to define required gaps at top and bottom.
My question is, exists here solution without wrapping span?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug with IE (at least with IE9); when you set list-style:none, it jumps back to the top. So either my text sits stupidly at the top of the screen, or I have an ugly bullet point I can't get rid of. Thanks again, IE.

Comment: Beautiful, even for multi-line wrapping!

Answer (score 3):

```
li {
    height:200px; 
    line-height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
li span {
    vertical-align:middle; 
    display:inline-block; 
    line-height:1.2;
}

<li>
    <span>two<br />lines</span>
</li>
```

It should work.

EDIT : updated to see changes