# center vertically the content of a div

Tags: css, center

I have this `div`:

HTML:

```
<div draggable="false" id="coffe">Free coffee</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: rgb(26, 66, 108);
    font-family: roboto, Helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 67.125px;
    width: 1029.25px;
    height: 234.93749999999997px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: grey;
}
```

And I need to vertically center its content, which is "free coffee".

How can I do this? I tried with `vertical-align: middle;` but it doesn't work.

This is the fiddle file: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mb39/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center single- AND multi-line li text vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095165/center-single-and-multi-line-li-text-vertically)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952943/vertically-center-align-text

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649287/vertically-centering-inline-content-using-line-height

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify a `line-height` that matches the `<div>`'s height:

```
line-height: 235px;
```

See this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Mb39/1/)

Comment: Start another question, rather than moving the goalposts of this one.