# Set images in horizontal

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a carousel slider of images. In there some images/icons are smaller than others. And I want to align all the images/icons in the center without any extra classes for those small images. I was trying `vertical-align: middle;` or `display: inline-block;` and so on.

Screenshot_1.png is the example slider and Screenshot_2.png is the slider that I am looking for.
[image: Screenshot_1.png]
[image: Screenshot_2.png]

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="custom-carousel">
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example that may work for you to just use the inline-block with vertical-align.

```
.custom-carousel > .item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is a quick JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtqLL6hd/

Answer (score 0):

One can use the CSS flexbox technology to center items vertically.  See the following:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here is example code:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="custom-carousel" style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img.png" alt="img"></div>
</div>
```

There are also a number of similar Stack Exchange answers including:

[How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

[How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

[center vertically the content of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245736/center-vertically-the-content-of-a-div)

[Center a DIV horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)